# Need to add headers in existing data frame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pyspark-pandas, pyspark-schema, pyspark-transformer

I am loading a csv file like below, The file contain a header but i need to additional header over top of the line. I tried many ways in pyspark but end with zero.
Could anyone guide me further.

Sample Input
[image]

Sample output:

[image]

I loaded the file like below

```py
df=spark.read.csv(path,header=True,inferschema=True)
```

Over that i tried many ways to add a additional header but nothing  helps

Comment: Why not use additional column to indicate that header. Spark is clever enough to know how to optimise single value columns internally. If you are joining multiple such tables, then have a table name column is the right way

Comment: How about a wrapping all the columns inside a struct? You'd have only one column with named and typed subfields which looks like what you want.